# Matrices that commute with their transpose are diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Well, basically the title already captures my question. Given any matrix $M\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that satisfies $MM^T=M^TM$ one can follow that M is already diagonalizable. Here I mean the transpose of a matrix not the conjugate transpose. The argument for normal matrices is not that difficult but i dont know how to adapt it to this problem. Any help is apprechiated.

Comment: @JeanMarie i know how this works for normal matrices

Comment: the $T$ there means transpose or conjugate transpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot prove it because it is false. Consider $v=(1,i)^T$ and $M=vv^T$. Since $M$ is symmetric, we of course have $MM^T=M^TM$. However, as $v^Tv=0$, $M$ is a nonzero nilpotent matrix. Hence it is not diagonalisable.

Comment: So, what if $M$ has real entries (i.e., $M \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$)? Also, what if $M$ commutes with its **conjugate** transpose as suggested in Masacroso's comment? Would the statement then be true in both cases?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang In the two cases that you’ve mentioned, $M$ is a normal matrix, which is always diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. Since the OP has mentioned that they knew the proof for normal matrices, I think $M^T$ is not a typo and the OP did use $M^T$ to mean the usual matrix transpose.

Comment: I'll edit my question to clear up the confusion.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the answer, I guess my professor made a mistake then. Do you know if this changes if $M^T=-M$?

Comment: @Adronic That doesn’t change anything. Consider the $4\times4$ matrix $M=\pmatrix{0&vv^T\\ -vv^T&0}$ for instance, where $v$ is the vector in my answer. It is skew-symmetric and hence it commutes with its own transpose, but this new $M$ is still a nonzero nilpotent matrix (with $M^2=0\ne M$).

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Futhermore, for the given skew-symmetric matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&vv^T\\-vv^T&0\end{pmatrix}$, $I+M$ would be orthogonal (i.e., its inverse and transpose coincide), hence commute with its transpose, but not diagonalizable. So, orthogonal matrices, like symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices, need not be diagonalizable, even though they commute with their transposes.